# Scala val and var with collections

Tags: scala, collections, immutability, var, val

I want to understand better the following issue.
When should i use var and when val?

I know that there is a rule of thumb in Scala that we should use val.

For primitive types it's easy - we should use var only if we change a variable in a loop.

My first question is if there any better way to do that in Scala:

```
var sum = 0
while (condition) sum = sum + something
return sum
```

But same and more complicated is for collections.

1. We have the mutable or immutable collections
2. We have var and val for the pointers.

**I want to ask for each of the following if it's make sense (means could be, but not necessarily good practice), and when should we use each of the following options (what is good practice)**:

1. val mutable collection
2. var mutable collection
3. val immutable collection (can't be)
4. var immutable collection

**I also want to ask if changing a collection means to change it's pointer or it's elements, or both**.
Take a list for example. If I add an element I did a change. But what if I just want to update an element?

The reason I'm asking this question is that when we need to solve common problems, we need to change the collection and we can't use immutable val.

```
var list = List(1,2,3)
// this will not save the list with changes
while (condition) list :+ some_integer
return list
```

This topic is confusing for me in Scala.

I would appreciate if someone can make this topic more clear.
Thanks.

I want to understand this topic better. In others languages it's quiet clear, but in Scala it's a bit confusing.

Comment: It is really simple: never use `var`. At least, not until you have developed enough command of the language to be able to recognize those _extremely rare_ cases when you might actually need it. Same goes to "changing collections": just don't. Out of your four items, the only one you should ever use is `#3` (that you think "cannot be" for some reason). Also, while I have your attention, you should never use `return` either.

Comment: You almost never ever need to use a mutable collection, and most times when you need them is because of performance _(but not because the algorithm couldn't be expressed using immutable collections)_. - Anyways, in those cases, prefer a `private val` with a mutable collection if its scope is synchronous _(e.g. a single method)_ or a concurrent safe mutable pointer to a immutable collection if the scope is concurrently accessed.

Comment: Is better if you open a new question showing the meta-problem you are trying to solve so we can provide more precise advice. - But, in general, the answer will be a method in the stdlib or in **cats** or recursion.

Answer (score 3):

In your example code:

```
var sum = 0
while (condition) sum = sum + something
return sum
```

How one might do this without `var` really depends on what `condition` is. We can't give you a one-size-fits-all answer.

But I'll give you one specific example. Suppose we have an imperative method `getNext()` that returns an `Int`, and we want to stop summing once it returns a `-1`. In Java one might write:

```
int sum = 0;
int next;
while ((next = getNext()) != -1) {
  sum += next;
}
return sum;
```

In Scala I would write:

```
Iterator.continually(getNext())
  .takeWhile(_ != -1)
  .sum
```

here I'm using higher-order methods such as `continually` and `takeWhile`. If the shape of the problem were different, different higher-order methods might be the right ones.

As an aside, note that I did not use `return`. 99% of Scala code never uses `return` at all.

Answer (score 1):

That was my pain when I started learning Scala. So, I understand where you are coming from. The short answer: `val` with `immutable` collections, and create a new copy each time you want to change it.

Oversimplifying: For an immutable object or collection, when you want to make an update you (or the language under the hood) create a copy of that collection. The new copy will share the unchanged data with the old collection or object. So, it is memory efficient. Since the collection is immutable, and everything (pointer) in that collection points to something that is immutable. You should be safe making those references knowing that whatever you are referring to is not going to change.

So the way you'd structure Scala code using `val` differs from how you'd structure your Scala code using `var.` And because of that difference, this code snippet you gave will not be written this way. I am not sure what you are trying to achieve so, it is hard for me to rewrite it.

Let's say you want to add someInteger to the list if a condition applies to all elements of the list.

```scala
val newList = if (list.forall(elem => elem > 4)) list :+ someInteger else list
```

What is important here, is you have a new list that you would return.

And because of the rich collections and all the methods you have, you usually do not see traditional while and for loops in Scala code. What you might see in some cases is recursion.

Allow me to give another example

```scala
case class Account(value: Int){
  def deposit(amount: Int): Account = {
    this.copy(value = this.value + amount)
  }
}

val account = Account(0)
val updatedAccount = account.deposit(10)
```

This example shows two things:

1. updating account value required a copy of the account because `value` is immutable.
2. you need a new `val updatedAccount` to store the updated account.

This is the way you'd usually write code in Scala.

Finally, let's go through a list of accounts and close any account that has balance below zero

```scala
val updatedAccounts = accounts.map(account => if (account.value <0) account.close else account)
```

and in all the examples above we are using vals with immutable collections.
I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comment. 
So one thing is not clear to me. If I have a code that run a loop while a condition on a list is happening. I need to update the list in every iteration. How can I do this in Scala?
newList in your example is the list that I want, but I want that new list will become the new one in every iteration and I want to return it after the loop.

Comment: What do you mean by "every iteration" ? What are you iterating on ? Is it another list ? Or is it a plain old condition ? If so what is the condition driven by ? Is the related to your list ? Or is it related to something else ? Scala has a lot a different mechanism to solve this kind of thing but we need more information to help you.

Comment: both of case. Iterate on the list with condition or iterate on another collection and update the list.

Comment: Hey @nial, I am sorry I lost track of this thread. If you are still interested in an answer. Can you give an example of what you want to do. Maybe with examples. Like example input data, and example output date?